# Postgresql 8.2 service will not stop and uninstall

Tags: uninstall, postgresql

My system config is as follows:

System (running on Amazon EC2)

Ubuntu 10.04

---

Postgresql-8.2 installed and it is working.

```
ubuntu@ip:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql-8.2 status:
Running clusters: 8.2/main
```

When I try to shutdown the server, I get the error:

```
ubuntu@ip:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql-8.2 stop
* Stopping PostgreSQL 8.2 database server
* Insecure directory in $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 63.                         [fail]
```

Because of the above problem I am unable to do a clean uninstall of PostgreSQL. Any suggestion on how to fix this problem?

I have tried the following:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove postgresql-8.2
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get purge postgresql-*
```

None of them resolved the problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check if http://www.dangibbs.co.uk/journal/insecure-directory-in-envpath-while-running-with-t-switch-at-usrbinpg_ctlcluster helps you solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The permissions are wrong on one of your folders in your $PATH

do a

```
echo $PATH
```

and look at all your folders
mine looks like

/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

the folders are seperated by :'s

then **cd to every folder and ls -l to see permissions**

**if the folder is not 755 (drwxr-xr-x) then do a**

```
sudo chmod 755 sbin/
```

finally when you are sure you havent missed anything run your

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Hope this helped everyone!